# Conditionally removing a grouping in reporting services

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that is displayed with a grouping per location. For example, I have stores grouped by geographic regions.

I would like conditionally to remove the group so that, instead of being grouped by regions, all the stores are simply listed alphabetically.

Is this possible? The regions are in a group and the stores are in a detail group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the control with the grouping, you simply make the grouping conditional on something, usually on a parameter. And also change visibility of the grouping header/footer.

In the "Grouping and Sorting" dialog for the control you'd have the grouping something like

```
 = iif(Parameters!GrpByRegion.Value, Fields!StoreRegion.Value, "")
```

In the "Hidden" property for the grouping header (say in a table) you'd have

```
 = iif(Parameters!GrpByRegion.Value, false, true)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing, but I've let the question go as I thought it was a not really nice looking hack. But I guess it's the only way to go.

Comment: @Gimly: I reckon it is a hack because it has to specified in 2 places. If we could link the two properties it'd be better (eg  Hidden = rsitems(myControl)!groupingIsConstant etc)

Comment: Exactly, or be able to specify in a group if, when it is hidden, we want to hide the children as well or show the children but acting as if there was no group.