# SSRS Tablix Group and alternate row color

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

In my report I have Tablix1 with groups and detail.

When I pass parameter for **Student level** report then I get the following:

```
School  
   Grade   
      Teacher  
         Student  
              Question1  
              Question2  
              Question3  
              Question4
```

I want Question rows in alternate color for above report.

I get alternate row color by using this in backgroundcolor:

```
=IIf(RowNumber("Groupname")  Mod 2 = 1, "White","Blue")
```

When I pass parameter for **Teacher level** report then I Student groups get dropped and I get the following:

```
School  
   Grade   
      Teacher  
              Question1  
              Question2  
              Question3  
              Question4
```

I do not get alternate color for **Teacher level** report.I want Question 1,2,3,4 rows in alternate color

Both reports are in the same Tablix.

Comment: what is "Groupname"? And did you implement this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745217/conditionally-removing-a-grouping-in-reporting-services to "drop" the student group? 
AFAIK really dropping a group based on a parameter is not possible except if you have 2 separate tablixes and hide one of them entirely. Some more info should help to answer the question.

Comment: I am not dropping the group . If it is teacher level report then I do not want students so I am grouping student group by teacher and then hiding it so that there will not be 2 teacher group.           If the report is student level the groupname is student. If report is Teacher then groupname is Teacher.

Comment: Any suggestion for his issue? I am new to SSRS and need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the Backgroundcolor of row

=iif(RunningValue(Fields!Classification.Value,CountDistinct,"studentname") Mod 2 , "White","Blue")
Worked for both reports ( Both parameters)

Comment: Background color of what? My child group or the parent group? How do I get to the backgroundcolor of row? Thanks for sharing the answer :)